# how to execute a nested group aggregate functions with multi groupBy columns using entity framework and linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, aggregate-functions

I have a select statement as following.

```
SELECT Doc_Id term 
FROM [Inverted_Index]
```

how can I do something like the following statement using entity framework and linq ?

```
select max(count(term))
from inverted_index
where doc_id = Given_doc_id
group by doc_id, term
```

Given_doc_id: is known and passed by application.

I tried to solve this issue as a workaround by creating the following view and select max(freq)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Terms_Freq_Per_Doc]
AS (SELECT Doc_Id, term, count(term) freq
FROM [Inverted_Index]
group by Doc_Id, term);
```

... but also not success because I could not be able to add view to entity diagram .edmx because restrictions of adding view to .edmx

please help solving this, how to get max(count(term)) ???

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below code could help you:

```
    int maxTerm = (from o in db.Inverted_Index
                            where o.Doc_Id == Given_doc_id
                            group o by new { o.Doc_Id, o.term } into g
                            select g).Max(p => p.Select(o => o.term).Count());
```

Comment: very close, but there is error in syntax, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
int maxTerm = db.Inverted_Index
                        .Where(i => i.Doc_Id == Given_doc_id)
                        .GroupBy(inv => new { inv.Doc_Id, inv.term })
                        .Select(g => new { g.Key.Doc_Id, g.Key.term, cnt = g.Count() })
                        .Max(x =>x.cnt);
```